# Decrypt file rijndael 128 bit

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

In my app I download files from a server which are encrypted with Rijndael 128 bit with a certain IV (for instance: start 0 with 16 bytes)

How can I decrypt such file in iOS? It's an encrypted PDF.

In C# I can encrypt it with `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`

I hope someone can help me with this..

Thanks in advance!